# Add timestamps to command output redirected to text file

Tags: windows-7, command-line, adb

I am writing adb logcat command output to the text file:

```
adb [-s device_id] logcat > logfile.txt
```

Unfortunately, in this case the logs don’t have timestamps.
Is there way to just insert timestamps (or whatever text) at the beginning of each line of the redirected command output?

**Update**: I found that simply using `logcat -v threadtime` ([example](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Debug-adb-logcat-Command-Log-Format-Control.html)) is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to leave my own answer here, since I am not using the above suggestion anymore.
The simpler way is just to use `logcat -v threadtime`, which ensures that logs have all the timestamps I need.

[[example](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Debug-adb-logcat-Command-Log-Format-Control.html)]

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are actually on some version of Windows and not really using MS-DOS.

If so, then a little VBScript should work.

timestampLog.vbs:

```
Dim str
Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
  str = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine now & " - " & str
Loop
```

Usage:

```
adb [-s device_id] logcat | cscript //nologo timestampLog.vbs >logfile.txt
```

Comment: p.s. right, it’s win-7. As “ms-dos” tag description says, it “…also applies to Windows command-shell questions.”

Comment: I had to modify the second last line to `WScript.StdOut.WriteLine now & " - " & str` in order for the content to be sent to the file.  Otherwise it would print to console and the file would be empty.

Comment: @Aerankas - I don't know why I had StdErr, as it doesn't make sense :-/ I've updated the answer. Thanks.